# Blob load from database

Tags: spring, video, thymeleaf, load, display

I want display the video blob. How can I process for the src?

```
<div class="jumbotron col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3" th:each="film: ${films}">
     <p th:text="${film.description}" />
     <p th:text="${film.genre}" />
    <p th:text="${film.nomFilm}" />
    <p th:text="${film.titre}"/>   <video src="${film.filmvideo}"></video>  
</div>
```

Comment: @Lob 
 private byte[]   filmvideo ;

Comment: Try as: `<video src = window.URL.createObjectURL( ${film.filmvideo} ) > </video>` ... Also try to create your video tag with other settings like `width` and `height` and `controls` etc...

Comment: thank you for you help , but it doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="400" controls>
        <source th:src="${film.filmvideo}" />
    </video>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @borchvm the problem was from the source src for object type blob , the solution without javascript is just that

Comment: @Billy_boy does not explain it to me, please add context in your answer to can help future users learn

Comment: @borchvm i stored a field of type BLOB in my database and i wanted display it and i had a problem for how to add a src of type object blob , the first solution was with javascript "URL.createObjectUrl(${myblobVariable})" , i finally found a solution , with thymleaf it's possible to do it like this : <video width="400" controls>
        <source th:src="${film.filmvideo}" />
    </video>

Comment: @Billy_boy you can edit your answer and add the explanation there, instead of in the comment, thanks